# 1548 [Warning] Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT

Tags: mysql, mysqlbinlog

I got the following warning running the simple statement and I was curious as to why I got it:

```
UPDATE `Table1` 
SET `City`='Miami', 
    `ExpDate`='201227', 
    `User`='JDoe', 
    `UpdDate`='2015-02-17 16:11:25' 
WHERE `id` = 61`
```

Here is the `Table1` structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `Table1` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `User` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `City` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `ExpDate` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `UpdDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Unique_Index` (`User`,`City`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `ALT1_IDX_Table1` (`User`,`City`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=64 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

Full Error from log:

`2015-02-17 16:10:08 1548 [Warning] Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT. Statement is unsafe because it invokes a trigger or a stored function that inserts into an AUTO_INCREMENT column. Inserted values cannot be logged correctly. Statement: UPDATE`Table1
        `SET`City`='Miami',` 
ExpDate`='201227',` 
User`='JDoe',` 
UpdDate`='2015-02-17 16:11:25' 
        WHERE`id`= 61`

Comment: We need the table structure to identify the error. Edit: Especially the indexes, CREATE code would help.

Comment: @BrainFooLong - I posted the structure.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: Nearly, the complete CREATE TABLE code would help more. As of now there seems no error - Maybe you will find it when you search here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-rbr-safe-unsafe.html

Comment: @BrainFooLong - I posted the table structure

Comment: At first, remove the key `UNIQUE KEY id`, primary keys are itself unique. Than remove  `KEY ALT1_IDX_Table1`, you already have a UNIQUE key on that 2 fields. Than try again - I've got the errors everytime in combination with weird keys.

Comment: PS: Maybe the complete error from the log will help us to solve the problem.

Comment: @BrainFooLong - I posted the full errror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, the error show exactly what's wrong here.
`Statement is unsafe because it invokes a trigger or a stored function that inserts into an AUTO_INCREMENT column`
The error is not in the table itself, the error is in a trigger or procedure that fires when this table get's updated.

Comment: You are right.  I looked and there are like 5 triggers.  I am not too familiar with mySQL.  I guess a DBA should be able to solve the problem.  I have noticed a lot of people using Mixed Mode instead of Binary.

Comment: Maybe your DB was not fairly optimized for replications. Maybe there is some work to re-build, depends on your specific db structure. You should ask someone that made this database.